# CKEditor 5 adding caption to image

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I can create a DocumentFragment that contains an image element pretty easily like this:

```
  clickPasteImage(editorComponent: CKEditorComponent) {
    const editor = editorComponent.editorInstance;
    const docFragment = editor.model.change(writer => {
      const fragment = writer.createDocumentFragment();
      const e1 = writer.createElement('image', { src: TboxService.imageURL(this.image.id) });
      writer.append(e1, fragment);
      return fragment;
    });
    this.paste.emit({ content: docFragment, quote: false, obj: this.image });
  }
```

The receiver of the emitted event can insert this content and it comes up correctly.  What is interesting is the UI gives the user the option of adding a caption.

How do I add that caption from **writer** callback above?  (The object **this.image** optionally has text in it that could be used to set it for the user.)

More importantly, where is the documentation that defines what attributes are available for which element types and how the elements behave?  I only new about the **src** attribute from an example.

To add to understanding, at what point does the **createElement('image'** call get morphed into the following HTML?

```
<figure>
  <img src="....">
  <figcaption>....</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image caption is a "caption" element inside the "image" element. Check out this snippet.:

```
editor.model.change(writer => {      
    const image = writer.createElement( 'image', { src: 'https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/assets/img/umbrellas.jpg' } );
    writer.appendElement( 'caption', image );
    writer.appendText( 'Caption text', image.getChild( 0 ) );
    writer.append(image, editor.model.document.getRoot() );
});
```

Execute it and it will append add an image with a caption to the editor.

> More importantly, where is the documentation that defines what attributes are available for which element types and how the elements behave? I only new about the src attribute from an example.

There is no such documentation at this moment. The easiest way to learn more about the model is by browsing the `*editing.js` files of the [feature.](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-image)